# Selecting text from header names to add to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add some text to the bottom of my graph. I know to add text, but I'm not sure how to select this column header location in my data set to be the text that I'm adding to the bottom of the graph [My Data is included here.](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8aua823d4y33kta/TestData.csv)  I'd also like to make the one column heading in the data that says "System UpLoad Time = Jul 25 2017 18:53:32" as the text that I'm adding instead of "ADD TEXT HERE" in my code. How do I go about doing this without having to change all of my files around?

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)


TestData$Temp2 <- (TestData$Temp/10)
TestData$Temperature <- (TestData$Temp2*56)
TestData$Chlorophyll <- (TestData$Derivedchlorophyll*56)    


dat.m <- melt(TestData, id=c ("Depth", "Temp", "Temp2", "Specific Conductance [µS/cm]", "FlECO-AFL", "Beam Attenuation (1/m)", 
                            "Beam Transmission (%)", "Transmissometer voltage", 
                            "Fluorometer voltage", "CDOM Voltage", "CDOM (mg/m^3)", "Flag", "Derivedchlorophyll"))

plot<-ggplot(data=subset(dat.m, variable %in% c("PAR","Temperature", "Chlorophyll")), aes(value, Depth, colour = variable)) +
  geom_point() + scale_y_reverse() + scale_x_continuous( "PAR", 
  sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 56, name = "Chlorophyll (µg/L)\nTemperature (10 °C)"))


grid.newpage()
footnote <- "ADD TEXT HERE"
g <- arrangeGrob(plot, bottom = textGrob(footnote, x = 0, hjust = -0.1, vjust=0.1, gp = gpar(fontface = "italic", fontsize = 12)))
grid.draw(g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part, if "System UpLoad Time" is always in the same position of your headers, I'd use:

`footnote <- colnames(TestData)[15]`

Alternatively, if the position in your header varies between files use:

```
grep("System UpLoad Time =", colnames(TestData), value = T)
```

I'm not certain what you are trying to select in the first part of the question, or if it's actually the same question. Though some intuition with the above should work.

Also, it may be worth re-naming your question to suit the actual question - "Selecting text from header names" for example. As you say, you are aware of how to place the text below the ggplot graph.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted, I just didn't know the colnames command. I've also updated my question title.

Comment: No worries, `names()` will also do the same job

Comment: Do you know a way to select for the name of the file I am using if I want to add that as a footnote also? I'm using `TestData <- read.csv("~/Rtest/TestData.csv")` to pull my data, but the original file names have info that should be included as text below the graph as well.

Comment: @SteveG If only a couple of files, store the filename as a variable `filename <- "~/Rtest/filename.csv"`and then call that string into text the graph. If you're planning on looping across a directory of files, use `list.files(getwd())` to list all files in the directory. To get only part of the file name, look at using `strsplit()` on the file name string.